# Angular2-moment with Angular2-cli installation

Tags: angular, momentjs, angular-moment, angular2-cli, angular2-moment

I have installed `angular2-moment` into `angular2-cli`. While installing, `angular2-cli` does not have `system.js`, so where can I put these settings into?

https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment/#for-systemjs-users

Also I'm also getting following error:

[image: pipe missing]

Comment: What is your exact *Angular 2* version? I have tried using `"angular2-moment": "1.0.0-beta.1"` with a `"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.15"` generated project based on *Angular 2.0.0*. Everything seems to be working OK.

Comment: `angular 2.0.0` and `angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.15` and `angular2-moment ^1.0.0-beta.1`

Comment: OK, so you match my test landscape.

Comment: did you add configuration to system.js? because I'm not sure where to put that.

Comment: No, the Readme clearly states: **For System.js users**. *Angular-cli* doesn't use `system.js`, so don't bother with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the *moment* to your `package.json` under `dependencies`: `"angular2-moment": "^1.0.0-beta.1"`. Then install it via: `npm install --save`.

Since you most probably use *TypeScript*, install *Types* for the *moment* lib: `npm install @types/moment --save`.

Then you need to import the `MomentModule` in your desired module. Eg.: `import { MomentModule } from 'angular2-moment';`.

And thats it, now you can use the *moment pipes*.

Comment: I have two ngModule, If I include on child ngModule which is included in parent, then it does not work, but if I include it inside parent ngModule, then it starts working fine.  Do you know how I can solve that?

Comment: ahh.. had to put it in `export: [MomentModule]` in order to fix it inside sub module.

Answer (score 0):

Just inster in angular-cli.json at script array the path to moment.

```
"scripts": ["../node_modules/moment/moment.js"]
```